# When is it better to use "would" rather than simple past tense?

Tags: past-tense, would

Which of the following reads better:

"With the exception of this past Sunday, I could not attend church for the month of January and February (mostly due to the flu), but I rested assured knowing I could return any time I wanted."

Or

"With the exception of this past Sunday, I could not attend church for the month of January and February (mostly due to the flu), but I would rest assured knowing I could return any time I wanted."

Does meaning change in either of these sentences? Which one would be "proper" English -- to write *would rest* or *rested assured*? What are the rules for using *would* as the past of *will*?

Comment: Minor edits: Except the past Sunday, I could not attend the church in January and February, mostly due to a flue, knowing that I could return any time I wanted. 'rest assured' and 'knowing' look redundant. For varied use of WILL and WOULD, you may refer to MODALS.

Comment: @RamPillai *Flu* is a commonly used contraction of influenza, whereas a *flue* is basically a duct for exhaust gases. I wouldn't have pointed this out on any site but this one (dedicated to the English language).

Comment: @RamPillai You don't need a "the" before every noun. Trust me -- it is not the correct usage of it.

Comment: @RamPillai Minor edits to your minor edits: Except the past Sunday is missing a preposition. The correct form is: "Except FOR this past Sunday, I could not attend church in January or February because of the flu. Even then, I knew I could return any time I wanted." Also, "rest assured knowing" is actually not redundant. 

Further, do not go crazy with the determiners. Other languages like Spanish need them before every noun, but it is not the case in English. You corrected my sentence to "I could not attend the church." The "the" is in fact redundant.

Comment: @RamPillai Yes, people can make out very easily what an error and a typo are because they're the same thing. Typo is shorthand for "typographical error."

Comment: @RamPillai No offense, but I'd prefer someone with a strong command of writing to answer my question. I can't be correcting everyone's typos and grammatical missteps.

Your edits, no offense, made my statement worse. Mine was merely verbose, but yours fell short.